# How to build a correct SOAP request with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to format/build a request for this SOAP "service":
http://api.notificationmessaging.com/NMSOAP/NotificationService?wsdl

Ideally I would like to use the native PHP SOAP class, but I'm beginning to wonder if this class is not the cause of my problems.

The manual provides this example:

```
    <soapenv:Body>
        <api:sendObject>
            <arg0>
                <content>
                    <entry>
                        <key>1</key>
                        <value>
                        <![CDATA[
                        <table width="600">
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <font size="2" face="Arial">Our powerful algorithms already
                        found a matching profile that matches your criteria:
                        <br>Celina72&nbsp;</font>
                        <img src="http://mypath/to/my/image.gif" width="50"
                        height="50" border="0" />
                        </td>]]></value>
                    </entry>
                </content>
                <dyn>
                    <entry>
                        <key>FIRSTNAME</key>
                        <value>john</value>
                    </entry>
                </dyn>
                <email>johnblum@flowerpower.com</email>
                <encrypt>BdX7CqkmjSivyBgIcZoN4sPVLkx7FaXGiwsO</encrypt>
                <notificationId>6464</notificationId>
                <random>985A8B992601985A</random>
                <senddate>2008-12-12T00:00:00</senddate>
                <synchrotype>NOTHING</synchrotype>
                <uidkey>EMAIL</uidkey>
            </arg0>
        </api:sendObject>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the garbage that my PHP request produces (from __getLastRequest())

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://api.service.nsapi.emailvision.com/" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:sendObject/>
            <param1>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</param1>
            <param2>123456789</param2>
            <param3>BBBBBBBBBBBB</param3>
            <param4>2013-09-09T00:00:00</param4>
            <param5>NOTHING</param5>
            <param6>EMAIL</param6>
            <param7>
                <ns2:Map>
                    <item>
                        <key>2</key>
                        <value>TEST</value>
                    </item>
                </ns2:Map>
            </param7>
            <param8>
                <ns2:Map>
                <item>
                    <key>FIRSTNAME</key>
                    <value>John</value>
                </item>
            </ns2:Map>
            <ns2:Map>
                <item>
                    <key>LASTNAME</key>
                    <value>Smith</value>
                </item>
            </ns2:Map>
        </param8>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My call:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://api.notificationmessaging.com/NMSOAP/NotificationService?wsdl', array( 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0 ) );
```

The params look like this (modified with dummy data):

```
$email = 'john.smith@example.com';
$encrypt = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
$notification_id = 123456789;
$random = 'BBBBBBBBBBBB';
$senddate = '2013-09-09T00:00:00';
$synchrotype = 'NOTHING';
$uidkey = 'EMAIL';

$content = array();
$content[] = array(
    2 => 'TEST'
);

$dyn = array();
$dyn[] = array(
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'John'
);
$dyn[] = array(
    'LASTNAME' => 'Smith'
);

$params = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'encrypt' => $encrypt,
    'notificationId' => $notification_id,
    'random' => $random,
    'senddate' => $senddate,
    'synchrotype' => $synchrotype,
    'uidkey' => $uidkey,
    'content' => $content,
    'dyn' => $dyn
);
```

I then execute the request like this :

```
$res = $client->__soapCall( 'sendObject', array( $email, $encrypt, $notification_id, $random, $senddate, $synchrotype, $uidkey, $content, $dyn ) );
```

Why is PHP unable to format my request correctly? Is there a mor direct approach where I could write the XML "by hand" and then post it using cURL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Is there a more direct approach where I could write the XML?"

By using a [**SoapVar**](http://php.net/class.soapvar) and setting the *encode* parameter of the constructor to [`XSD_ANYXML`](http://php.net/soap.constants#constant.xsd-anyxml) you can write the raw XML.

There should be a way where the WSDL helps build the XML though.

You could try something like this:

```
$wsdl   = "http://api.notificationmessaging.com/NMSOAP/NotificationService?wsdl"; 
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                                        'trace' => true,
                                      )); 
try {

    $xml = '<arg0>
            <content>
                <entry>
                    <key>1</key>
                    <value>
                    <![CDATA[
                    <table width="600">
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <font size="2" face="Arial">Our powerful algorithms already
                    found a matching profile that matches your criteria:
                    <br>Celina72&nbsp;</font>
                    <img src="http://mypath/to/my/image.gif" width="50"
                    height="50" border="0" />
                    </td>]]></value>
                </entry>
            </content>
            <dyn>
                <entry>
                    <key>FIRSTNAME</key>
                    <value>john</value>
                </entry>
            </dyn>
            <email>johnblum@flowerpower.com</email>
            <encrypt>BdX7CqkmjSivyBgIcZoN4sPVLkx7FaXGiwsO</encrypt>
            <notificationId>6464</notificationId>
            <random>985A8B992601985A</random>
            <senddate>2008-12-12T00:00:00</senddate>
            <synchrotype>NOTHING</synchrotype>
            <uidkey>EMAIL</uidkey>
        </arg0>';

    $args = array(new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML));    
    $res  = $client->__soapCall('sendObject', $args);
    return $res;
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "Error: {$e}";
}

echo "<hr>Last Request";
echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()), "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks @quaspas, I like this approach much better. I tried this and I finaly got a response from the service. However it still does not work: I get the message "Message part arg0 was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)". I Tried removing part but then the message is "Message part content was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)". I may not be far from the solution, thanks to you :)

Comment: Got it! All that was missing was an enclosing <ns1:sendObject>. Now the other problem was that the documentation uses the namespace "api" for the API, but PHP returns it as "ns1". Why? "Forget it, Jake. It's SOAP." Thanks again @quaspas for your great help!

Comment: In case anyone's curious about the unanswered question in the preceding comment, the prefixes `ns1` and `api` don't by themselves mean anything; the important part is the URI it's bound to, using the `xmlns:ns1="http://api.service.nsapi.emailvision.com/"` attribute at the top of the document. You can give it whatever prefix you want by changing that attribute, or adding your own further at any point in the document.

Comment: Holy bloody hell. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much

Comment: thank you so much this code worked for me i was searching for this since from 30+ days

Comment: I am getting the following error.  Error: SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("sendObject") is not a valid method for this service in. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

i know that the topic is about 1 year old,
but i find some good informations in it, that give me a very good help , and i finaly succed to make it work with the php method sendObject()
so i hope my contribution will help others people too...

at first the call of **sendObject()** this way : **$client->__soapCall** seems not working at all
you have to call it directly : **$client->sendObject**

in this topic, i think that it is a using of the API of emailvision (smartfocus, now...) 
this method **sendObject** does not need a generated token by **openApiConnection()**

oki, now , it is the code to make it work

```
<?php


    $email = 'johann.******@gmail.com';
    $encrypt = '******************************';
    $notification_id = '**************';
    $random = '********************';
    $senddate = '2013-09-09T00:00:00';
    $synchrotype = 'NOTHING';
    $uidkey = 'EMAIL';


    $params = array(
        'arg0' => array(
            'content' => array( 1 => 'mon_test'),
            'dyn' => array( 'FIRSTNAME' => 'yoyo'),
            'email' => $email,
            'encrypt' => $encrypt,
            'notificationId' => $notification_id,
            'random' => $random,
            'senddate' => $senddate,
            'synchrotype' => $synchrotype,
            'uidkey' => $uidkey
        )
    );


    $client = new       SoapClient('http://api.notificationmessaging.com/NMSOAP/NotificationService?wsdl', array(  'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0  ) );

    $res = $client->sendObject( $params );

echo "<br /><br /><br />";
echo "REQUEST 1 :" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) . "<br />";
echo "RESPONSE 1 :" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()) . "<br /><br /><br />";
```

?>

you have to know that $encrypt ,$notification_id , $random are generated by creating a transactionnal message, you can get this informations in the interface of campagn commander

take care of the schema of input xml, there is a node arg0, then you have to make a level arg0 in your array parameters

to make it work directly with xml :

```
<?php
$wsdl   = "http://api.notificationmessaging.com/NMSOAP/NotificationService?wsdl"; 
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'trace' => true,  )); 
try {

    $xml = '

            <ns1:sendObject>
                <arg0>

                    <content>
                        <entry>
                            <key>1</key>
                            <value>
                                <![CDATA[
                                <table width="600">
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <font size="2" face="Arial">Our powerful algorithms already found a matching profile that matches your criteria:
                                <br>Celina72&nbsp;</font>
                                <img src="http://mypath/to/my/image.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0" />
                                </td>]]>
                            </value>
                        </entry>
                    </content>

                    <dyn>
                        <entry>
                            <key>FIRSTNAME</key>
                            <value>john</value>
                        </entry>
                    </dyn>

                    <email>johann*******@gmail.com</email>
                    <encrypt>*********************</encrypt>
                    <notificationId>**************</notificationId>
                    <random>**********************</random>
                    <senddate>2008-12-12T00:00:00</senddate>
                    <synchrotype>NOTHING</synchrotype>
                    <uidkey>EMAIL</uidkey>

                </arg0>
            </ns1:sendObject>



        ';

    $args = array(new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML));    
    $res  = $client->__soapCall('sendObject', $args);
    //return $res;
} 
catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "Error: {$e}";
}

echo "<hr>Last Request";
echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()), "</pre>";

echo "<hr>Last Response";
echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()), "</pre>";

?>
```

it s important to write the first node like this : `<ns1:sendObject>`

`<api:sendObject>` does not work