# How to make a php SOAP call

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, wsse

I am having trouble setting the body of a PHP SOAP call. I believe I am close just dont know how to get it in the correct format.

Here is what I have thus far in PHP

```
    $client = new SoapClient('http://url');
    $username='username';
    $password='password';

    $headers='
        '.$username.'
        '.$password.'
    ';

    $securityTags = new SoapVar($headers, XSD_ANYXML);

    $header=new SoapHeader("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security",$securityTags,true);

    $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));

    //HOW DO I SET THE BODY????
    $params = array('deal'=>'PT10M', 'StoreIds'=>64);
    return $client->__soapCall("PullDeals", array('searchCriteria'=>$params));
```

Below is what the request should look like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:deal="http://url.com" xmlns:ns="http://url" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-145" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>YOUR_USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">YOUR_PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">JQT6P7Zd3COZerXkREww2g==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2013-11-19T22:18:54.122Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:PullDeals>
         <ns:searchCriteria>
            <deal:MaxElapsedSinceUpdate>PT10M</deal:MaxElapsedSinceUpdate>           
            <deal:StoreIds><arr:long>64</arr:long></deal:StoreIds>
         </ns:searchCriteria>
      </ns:PullDeals>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare your request to the what the request should look like add `'trace' => true` to your soap client.

`$client = new SoapClient("my.wsdl", array('trace' => true));`

[and then use `echo $client->__getLastRequest();` to spit out the XML.](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php)

I usually just view it on the page with chrome's Inspector to see it nicely indented.

You can reformat your call accordingly after you see how it is being formed.

[Failing that you can hard code the XML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723216/how-to-build-a-correct-soap-request-with-php/18725930#18725930)